# Integrating with Google Drive from a Chrome packaged app

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to make a Chrome packaged app integrate with Google Drive? Specifically, I'm looking to make an app that will sync user's files to Google Drive, be packaged (not hosted), and not have to rely on a secondary add-on app.

However, when a user opens a file from the Google Drive interface, I can't make Google Drive redirect to my packaged app, can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible currently. You need a hosted app to receive the redirect from the Google Drive user interface.

If you don't need to handle a redirect from the Drive user interface, you can create a Google Documents List API application that manages a user's files in their Drive. This can e a non-hosted, packaged app.

Comment: Would this be possible with http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app.identity.html?